# SQL: ?Create a VIEW from 3NF tables to look like a single row Repeating Group

Tags: view, db2, teradata, database-normalization, denormalization

We have a legacy table, containing repeating groups.

We want to swap to a normalised parent child, and then create a view that looks exactly like the old table.  We can upgrade the system progressively with no impact.

I'm having some trouble getting my head around how to write the view efficiently - there's a lot of data behind it (100s of millions of rows). We can do it in DB2 and/or Teradata

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkHQl.png)

OLD_TABLE

```
 PID 
 CID_COUNT -- count of values used 
 CID_1
 CVALUE_1
 CID_2
 CVALUE_2
```

NEW_PARENT_TABLE

```
PID
CID_COUNT
```

NEW_CHILD_TABLE

```
PID
CID
CVALUE
```

Comment: It might help your question to show some actual tangible data, rather than just a skeleton of table design.

Comment: Added and even put in colours

Comment: This looks like Excel/spreadsheet data to me.  Please post data as _tables_, which is how SQL represents its data.

Comment: Yep it's an XL mockup.. Nope can't paste data or DDL, I'd get sacked.
Let's pretend that OLD_TABLE and NEW_PARENT_TABLE and NEW_CHILD_TABLE are TABLES. and PID NAME etc are columns, or fields. Does that help you?

Comment: What's the actual number of repeated values? And what's your Teradata release?

Comment: Is `CID_1` always `1` and  `CID_2` always `2`, etc.? If not how is the order of columns in `new_view` determined?

Comment: Multiple scenarios.
- Some have up to 70 single column repeating groups. 
- Some have up to 30 repeats of 7 columns
- Some have multiple repeating groups of multiple columns.
We've lost some source data due to the source data exceeding the repeating group slots. I want to fix this legacy mess using normalised tables, without disrupting the existing ETL, and provide an upgrade path.
Tall ask :)

Comment: Yes CID_1 is always 1, CID_2 is 2,  - the field is populated by the ETL tool (tcVision) based on the array row number in the ADABAS/Natural array (which is stored as part of the parent record).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Db2 11.1.0.0 or above, or Db2 Warehouse, this code will give you the answer you want.

```
DROP TABLE NEW_PARENT_TABLE;
DROP TABLE NEW_CHILD_TABLE;

CREATE  OR REPLACE VIEW OLD_TABLE (PID, NAME, CID_COUNT, CID_1, CVALUE_1,  CID_2, CVALUE_2)
AS (VALUES 
    (123,'FRED',2,1   ,'Stilton',2  ,'Cheddar')
,   (124,'MARY',1,1   ,'Butter' ,null,null)
,   (125,'BOB', 0,null,null     ,null,null)
)
;
CREATE TABLE NEW_PARENT_TABLE (
      PID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , NAME CHAR(4) NOT NULl UNIQUE
    , CID_COUNT SMALLINT NOT NULL
    ) ORGANIZE BY ROW
;
INSERT INTO NEW_PARENT_TABLE
SELECT DISTINCT PID, NAME, CID_COUNT FROM OLD_TABLE
;
CREATE TABLE NEW_CHILD_TABLE (
      PID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES NEW_PARENT_TABLE
    , CID INT NOT NULL
    , CVALUE VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
    , PRIMARY KEY ( PID, CID )
    ) ORGANIZE BY ROW
;
INSERT INTO NEW_CHILD_TABLE
SELECT N.*
FROM OLD_TABLE O
,   TABLE(VALUES (O.PID, O.CID_1, O.CVALUE_1)
            ,    (O.PID, O.CID_2, O.CVALUE_2)
            ) AS N (PID, CID, CVALUE )
WHERE
    N.CID IS NOT NULL;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW NEW_VIEW AS
SELECT PID, CID_COUNT
,      MAX(CASE WHEN CID = 1 THEN CID    END) AS CID_1
,      MAX(CASE WHEN CID = 1 THEN CVALUE END) AS CVALUE_1
,      MAX(CASE WHEN CID = 2 THEN CID    END) AS CID_2
,      MAX(CASE WHEN CID = 2 THEN CVALUE END) AS CVALUE_2
 FROM NEW_PARENT_TABLE
 LEFT JOIN NEW_CHILD_TABLE USING (PID)
 GROUP BY PID, CID_COUNT
 ;
 SELECT * FROM NEW_VIEW

 PID CID_COUNT CID_1 CVALUE_1 CID_2 CVALUE_2
 --- --------- ----- -------- ----- --------
 123         2     1 Stilton      2 Cheddar
 124         1     1 Butter    NULL NULL
 125         0  NULL NULL      NULL NULL
```

If on DB2 (for LUW) 10.5, use `ON` not `USING` in the `NEW_VIEW` and qualify the columns. If on DB2 10.1 or less, also remove the `ORGANIZE BY ROW`

Comment: You might find the NEW_VIEW is more efficient if you use a JOIN for each CID value and avoid the `GROUP BY`.  You would be best testing with your real data/environment to see which works best...

Comment: Thanks, will get onto testing it now.Thanks for your assistance. :)